# Ruby on Rails: In Json-API passing parameters to inner serializer of compound document

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a ruby/rails JSON-API application using jsonapi-serializer let us say we want to support a query like:

```
https://example.com/movies/100?include=actors
```

Suppose that we have a custom attribute for the ActorSerializer that requires some data that is not available in the model. Say for example the current location of actors:

```
class ActorSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer

    set_type :actor
    attributes :first_name, :last_name

    attribute current_location do |object, params|
        params[:actor_locations][object.id]
    end
end
```

Further suppose we are getting the actor location data from an external website that gives the locations of all the actors in one query, and for performance issues we do not wish to make more than one call to this other website per request. Thus we do not want our current_location custom method to have to call the external website as a movie can have_many actors. Instead we have the query done in the controller method before it creates the json serializer object to be rendered.

Although I can see how to handle passing the location data as a parameter to make a ActorSerializer in the Actor controller, I am not sure how to get the data passed in there from the Movie controller that would presumably use a serializer something like:

```
class MovieSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer

    set_type :movie
    attributes :title, :year, :rating

    has_many :actors

end
```

Now I am not particular about the data getting there as a serializer parameter. As far as I know there may be some other way for a custom method in an inner serializer in a compound document to get at data that the controller has access to. Some kind of globally available data across the whole request or the like? I am new to ruby and rails. Just looking for a good solution (my actual problem is not about movies and actors but more complicated).

Comment: Think I see a solution to my problem. Being new to ruby and rails I did not realize I could add extra instance data to a model object that is not reflected in the db. It seems I can create getter and setters for the location to the Actor ActiveRecord which the Actor Serializer in turn will have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my problem resulted from presuming that ActiveRecords could only have instance data that was in the corresponding db record.

So all I had to do was make an attribute for the extra data like:

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    attr_accessor :current_location
    ...
end
```

With this done the controller can make the query to the external service and update all the actor records for the movie with the results. The serializer then can include the locations from this attribute with no need for any extra parameters passed to the serializer method.

Comment: While I am going with this solution and it works, I am gonna hold off checking it as the best answer since as far as I know there is a better way to do it, and also it is a bit gratuitous for one to judge their own answer as best too quickly.